# 404 on Wordpress post permalinks

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, apache2

I'm getting a 404 when I click permalinks to my posts.  I updated the `.htaccess` file per the [documentation instructions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#Creating_and_editing_.28.htaccess.29) but I still get them.  That `.htaccess` code is in my `/blog/` directory.

In my wp-admin control panel, I have it configured to do "post name" permalinks.  The post permalinks work fine when I use the default, but they are 404'ing when I use the "post name" permalink setting.

Background: I'm on Apache/2.2.20 (Ubuntu) Server.

Comment: Are you sure it's happening because of .htaccess ?

Comment: Is this for a custom post type? On a recently created page? Sometimes you have to load the permalinks page again when that happens, I don't know why - but that fixes the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure why this is happening.  Reloading the permalink page doesn't fix it

Comment: Is your wordpress installed in the `/blog/` directory?  Your .htaccess needs to be in the root directory where wordpress is installed.

Comment: The .htaccess is in `/blog/`, and in my WordPress Address (URL) and Site Address (URL) are set to there.

Comment: At firsr change the paramlink setting and then Temporarily rename the .htaccess file and change the paramlinks again to your desired choice of formay and see whether wordpress creates a new one or not ?

Answer (score 1):

Just updating the .htaccess file would not do the trick. You need to find out if your mod_rewite.c module is enabled. If not, you need to enable it by going to console and typing in this:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

and afterwards restart your apache server.

```
service apache2 restart
```

If even that doesnt work, probably your userdir module is not enabled. For this reason you need to enable it

```
sudo a2enmod userdir
```

and then try enabling the rewrite module if still not enabled.

You can read up on this further [here](http://seventhsoulmountain.blogspot.com/2014/02/wordpress-permalink-ubuntu-problem-solutions.html).

Answer (score 0):

Is your mod_rewrite on?
Otherwise you'll need full URL like http://example.com/index.php/yyyy/mm/dd/post-name/

Comment: I have `RewriteEngine On` in the .htaccess

Comment: With follow all?
and Globally enabled?

Comment: This is my .htaccess http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#Creating_and_editing_.28.htaccess.29

Answer (score 0):

If only the "post name" setting doesn't work, it might be due to a conflict, maybe you have a post with a name that's also present on another post, page or category.

Answer (score 0):

I Got Answer. It's easy only.

1) Go to WAMP logo in right-bottom of Task-bar of Windows.

2) Click left button

3) then Apache -> Apache Modules

4) Tic(select) the **rewrite_module**

5) that's all.